# jQuery - hide parent if all children affected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a search function for multiple `ul`'s using `.keyup()` on an `input`. If there is a match it `.show()` the `li` and for the other ones it does .`hide()`.

```
jQuery('.brandsearch').keyup(function(event) {
    var inputValue = jQuery(".brandsearch").val().toLowerCase();
    jQuery(".brands-group li").each(function(event) {
        if(jQuery(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) == -1) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

How do I climb up the hierarchy to also hide the entire `ul` if all `li`'s inside it are hidden?

HTML layout:

```
<input type="text" class="brandsearch">

<ul class="brands-group">
   <li>Adidas</li>
   <li>Nike</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this:

```
if (jQuery('.brands-group li:visible').length == 0) {
   jQuery('.brands-group ul').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.brandsearch').keyup(function(event) {
    var inputValue = jQuery(".brandsearch").val().toLowerCase();
    jQuery(".brands-group li").each(function(event) {
         var $parent = jQuery(this).closest('ul');
         if(jQuery(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) == -1)
         {
              jQuery(this).hide();
              if(jQuery('>li:visible', $parent).length == 0) $parent.hide();
         } else {
             jQuery(this).show();
             if($parent.is(':hidden')) $parent.show();
         }
    });
});
```